# On the fly image resizing and uploading to amazon s3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, upload, amazon-s3, swfupload, plupload

I am looking to upload images to amazon s3. Those images should be re sized to two sizes a thumbnail and a normal size. The resize should be done on client side to reduce server bandwidth. Then information about the images should be stored in a db using asp.net MVC.

Preferably a plugin would be the best option to do so.

Can anyone please help me in choosing the right plug in or steps to accomplish this?

I have researched a lot and came across plupload and swfupload but I got very confused as to accomplish the very simple tasks above.

Answer (score 0):

First hit on google: [SWFUpload Resize Image on the client demo](http://demo.swfupload.org/v250beta3/resizedemo/index.php).

Quote from the demo page:

> This demo shows how SWFUpload can
>   resize images on the client side.
>   Images resized before being uploaded
>   to the server. Then some JavaScript is
>   used to download the thumbnail and
>   display the resized image without
>   reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

Jumploader can also create thumbnails clientside. You can accomplish it with theese parameters. There are more parameters but they can all be found in the documentation. Jumploader is a java applet i opposition to swfuploader which is flash.

```
<param name="uc_uploadScaledImages" value="true"/>
<param name="uc_scaledInstanceNames" value="thumb1,thumb2"/>
<param name="uc_scaledInstanceDimensions" value="150x150xcrop,500x300xfit"/>
<param name="uc_scaledInstanceQualityFactors" value="600,900"/>
```

Good luck :-)